# c++ Macro Overloading is not working

Tags: c++, macros

I am trying to overload a c++ preprocessor macro depending on the number of arguments..

For example, I want to do this:

```
FOO(1, 2, 3)   //==> expandsto FOO3(1,2,3)
FOO(1, 2)      //==> expandsto FOO2(1,2)
```

This is what I've done:

```
#define GET_MACRO(_1,_2,_3,NAME,...) NAME
#define FOO(...) GET_MACRO(__VA_ARGS__, FOO3, FOO2)(__VA_ARGS__)

#define FOO2(A, B)      std::cout<<"2 arguments"<<std::endl;
#define FOO3(A, B, C)   std::cout<<"3 arguments"<<std::endl;

int main() {

    FOO(1,2,3)

    return 0;
}
```

In VC++, however, the exact code above gives me a compiler error:

```
expected a ";"
```

What did I do wrong..?

**UPDATE:**

In fact, I realized this works on Ideone  [>>>LINK<<<](http://ideone.com/NopvtD)... It doesn't work on Visual Studio 12..
Why is this.. and if VS doesn't support this type of macro overloading.. what are the alternatives..?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to run the preprocessor separately to see just the processed text output?

Comment: Do you mean Visual Studio 2012, or Visual C++ 12?  Or do you really mean Visual Studio 12.xx, which is sold under the name "Visual Studio 2013"?

Comment: I don't know if this is your issue, but I understand that the current VC++ preprocessor is not conformant, and that as a result source ported from other platforms which uses tricky preprocessor logic often breaks.

Comment: Please avoid the preprocessor for complex things. You can then live in the luxury of the full power of a compiler and type safety.

Answer (score 4):

this is VC++ Bugs of `__VA_ARGS__`

try this

```
#define ID(x) x
#define GET_MACRO(_1,_2,_3,NAME,...) NAME
#define FOO(...) ID(GET_MACRO(__VA_ARGS__, FOO3, FOO2)(__VA_ARGS__))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was driving me crazy because I was trying to fix it within my equivalent of GET_MACRO, which was too late as it still left the wrong macro being chosen. I can't believe the workaround was so simple.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's Visual studio bug, your code is valid (I can compile it with GCC). But it's bad style anyway.

```
#define FOO2(A, B)      std::cout<<"2 arguments"<<std::endl; // add `do {...} while (0)` construction
#define FOO3(A, B, C)   std::cout<<"3 arguments"<<std::endl;

int main() {

    FOO(1,2,3) // Put `;` here

    return 0;
}
```

Code should look like this:

```
#define FOO2(A, B)      do {std::cout<<"2 arguments"<<std::endl;} while (0)
#define FOO3(A, B, C)   do {std::cout<<"3 arguments"<<std::endl;} while (0)

int main() {

    FOO(1,2,3); // Looks like normal function now!

    return 0;
}
```

What is that `do {} while (0)` thing, you may ask? It prevents programmers from using your macro like this: `FOO2(1, 2) << "text";`.

Comment: Don't omit trailing `;` in expressions like this; you don't want to encourage `FOO(1,2,3) << std::flush;`, do you?  If you want a semicolon at the call site, use `do { contents; } while(false)`